# Select Specific data in R- Date Range For the data

Tags: r, datepicker, dataframe, quantmod

I am new to **R** and I am trying to select certain data range and plot it from 2013-05-01.However, the data being downloaded is from the beginning from 2007 -01-03. But I want to exclude the first six years and plot the data from 2013, May. 
Is it possible for me to do that? I have used the date function but I am guessing that isn't working. 
Can anyone help me on this issue?

PS: The code is attached.

```
library(quantmod)
library(tseries)
library(FinCal)
#downloading data

getSymbols('DRYS')
retdrys<-diff(DRYS$DRYS.Adjusted)/DRYS$DRYS.Adjusted
retdrys[is.na(retdrys)]<-0
#plot data from 2013-05-01
plot(retdrys,date>"2013-05-01")
```

I can plot the data from the beginning but if I have to plot the data for certain range, how do I do that?

Comment: `plot(retdrys['2013-05-01::']) `

Comment: @Khashaa, why don't you post this as an answer so Vishal can accept it and the question can be marked answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chartSeries` from `PerformanceAnalytics`. This plotting function has a nice built-in argument, `subset` that you can use to specify a range of dates.

Here's a few examples:

```
require(PerformanceAnalytics)
chartSeries(retdrys,subset = c('2013-04','2014'))  #Plot from April 2013 to the end of 2014
chartSeries(retdrys,subset = '2011')  #Plot from the beginning to the end of 2011
chartSeries(retdrys,subset = '2010-08') #Plot only for the month of August
```